# Browse Abcmouse.com on ubuntu

Tags: flash

I am trying to get ubuntu on home PC. Sometimes my kid use that PC and he browses mostly abcmouse.com. My recent experience were that abcmouse.com doesn't runs on ubuntu operating systems. Is there a way I can run those sites or need to wait fom abcmouse.com officially available on linux machine which I don't see going to happen soon.

Comment: What do you mean " abcmouse.com doesn't runs on Ubuntu"?

Comment: Nice response Mitch! On Xubuntu 13.10 ABC mouse graphics are illegible and all green. I am assuming the original post was referencing something like that. I am looking for a fix in Linux as well but I assume it is the website provider that has to modify settings to view in a Linux format.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from their FAQ:

> #### What are the system requirements to run ABCmouse.com?
>
> A: ABCmouse.com can be used on any computer or mobile device that has access to the Internet and is capable of running Flash version 10.2 or higher. For the best experience, you should have a broadband connection to the Internet, such as DSL, cable, or satellite.
>
> For iPad/iPhone users, we have created an app that allows you to access our site even though the iPad/iPhone is not compatible with Adobe Flash. For more information about accessing ABCmouse.com from these devices, please read directly below.

So, as long as you have Flash version 10.2 or better it should run.